# Using regex to ignore invalid syntax

Tags: python, regex

https://regex101.com/r/jK9mH3/1
That's the link to my regex, in order to not take up all the page i put it there, im trying to make it output a0, then a-z then aa-aq.

EDIT: Ok that was terrible im sorry, i need to run a program which checks the variable names of all dictionaries, but it wont be basic, i need it to check all different types of syntax like the ones listed in the checker, so it needs to be able to recognize that d = "{}" isnt actually a dictionary that its a string and that #z = {} is a comment not a dictionary. The output on the website will be a0, then a-z with no random z's in-between and then aa-aq (that is, aa, ab, ac, ad etc.)

Comment: Please describe what you want to detect! All variable names in front of `=`? Or something else?

Comment: What are you're trying to accomplish? Why ignore invalid syntax?

Comment: in theory that's not possible. regular expression is less powerful than context free grammar.

Answer (score 2):

Although your question doesn't make a lot of sense, I believe that you're trying to detect valid python syntax in a given string.

Do NOT use regular expression for this. Use a lexer/parser for this. It's designed to handle the complex structures found in a language like python.

[Guide to Lexing and Parsing](http://parsingintro.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: i have to use something like that, sorry i was in a rush. I mean i need to get the variable names for all the dictionaries. So if it was d = "{ }" it wouldnt print d because that isnt a dictionary but if it was d ={}; e = {} it would print both d and e because they are valid.